# Access a controller variable in all the views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, scope, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have this `@event` variable in a controller and i want to access this `@event` variable across all the views.I dont want to make this a global variable.Is there any other way to do it? I'm using rails 4.1.

Answer (score 5):

Initialize it in ApplicationController's before_action?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :init

  def init
    @event = ...
  end
end
```

Comment: This @event which is defined in EventsController.rb is accessible in the corresponding view file index.html.erb but i want to use it in another view feedback.html.erb. Only in that view. Any help

Comment: Consider using a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, if you have a variabale like :

```
@event="Spectacle 1"
```

You can access on this varibale in your html.erb files with this writing:

```
<%= @event %>
```